# How to retrieve all available routes between two nodes with Overpass API

Tags: routes, geolocation, maps, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm building an app which is provide the Map view (OpenLayers) for particular city(e.g. "London") with metro stations markers. So, user can click on pair of markers and I have to evaluate the shortest route between them.

As geodata source I decided to use **Overpass API** *(OSM read-only API)*. I'm new in OSM and Overpass API isn't cleared for me. So, I can't figure out how to fetch all available routes (railway, roads, etc) between two nodes with **Overpass QL**.

In summery, my goal is to fetch routes data, build graph representation from that and apply **Dijkstra's algorithm** in order to find shortest path. So, I stuck on the 1st step.

Comment: Isn't it possible for you to load the whole routing graph first and then do the Routing algorithm ?

Comment: Overpass API is _not_ a router, you can only fetch raw data in a certain area with it. You need to look at something like OSRM or Graphhopper for the actual routing. Take a look at [overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu), and especially its _wizard_  to explore the data.

Comment: @mmd I understand that _Overpass API_ isn't a complete routing service. I just want to figure out how to query that raw data for particular area and filter target information (route nodes) in terms of **Overpass QL**.

Comment: As mentioned, please check out overpass turbo wizard: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo/Wizard first.